# Syntax error in UPDATE statement vb.net in access database

Tags: vb.net

i'm getting an error when i'm trying to update my database

Syntax error in UPDATE statement
item:In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user.
error code: -2147217900

### errors: {System.Data.OleDb.OleDbErrorCollection}

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Ubah_Password
    Dim kns As New OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.15.0;data source =" & Application.StartupPath & "\database.accdb")
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String

```
Sub tampilkan()     'menampilkan semua user
    ds.Clear()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM USERLIST"
    da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, kns)
    da.Fill(ds, "USERLIST")
End Sub

Sub cariid()        'mencari id
    ds.Clear()
    sql = "select * from USERLIST where USERNAME = '" & LOGIN.USERNAME.Text & "'"
    da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, kns)
    da.Fill(ds, "USERLIST")
End Sub

Sub gantiid()   'mengganti password
    sql = "update USERLIST set USERNAME = '" & LOGIN.USERNAME.Text & "', PASSWORD= '" & renew.Text & "' where USERNAME ='" & LOGIN.USERNAME.Text & "'"
    kns.Open()
    da.UpdateCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, kns)
    da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    kns.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Ubah_Password_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    MAIN_MENU.Panel1.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Ubah_Password_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    tampilkan()

    MAIN_MENU.Panel1.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub oldpass_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles oldpass.TextChanged
    cariid()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    cariid()

    If ds.Tables("USERLIST").Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You Have Enter Wrong Password", "Warning!")
        oldpass.Clear()
        newpass.Clear()
        renew.Clear()
        oldpass.Focus()
    ElseIf ds.Tables("USERLIST").Rows.Count = 1 And newpass.Text <> renew.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("New Password And Confirmation Must Be Same!", "Warning!")
        newpass.Clear()
        renew.Clear()
        newpass.Focus()
    ElseIf ds.Tables("USERLIST").Rows.Count = 1 And newpass.Text = renew.Text Then
        gantiid()
        MessageBox.Show("Password Change Is Successful!", "Notice")
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What's in the OleDbErrorCollection? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: did you check your variables LOGIN.USERNAME.Text , renew.Text are filled? try to show message or print your sql update statement after the strings concatenation to check if your sql update being correctly formed.

Comment: You will want to parameterize your SQL statement (google search vb.net parameterized query and you'll find tons of examples), both to avoid SQL injection and to prevent SQL errors from users entering input that gets concatenated into your SQL.  If the user puts a quote ' into the input box your script will error out.

Comment: yep, if you don't use sql parameters instead of concatenating your strings, you'll be sorry. SQL injection will happen one day, guaranteed, just a matter of when.

Comment: so..what's the better solution? how to add parameter? i'm using ms .access as database. can anyone help me? i'm a beginner on this.